# batch file %0 string replace

Tags: batch-file, metaprogramming

I'm trying to output an XML document from a batchfile, using the `%0` operator and delimiters of the `for` command. When I include batch variables in the XML, they don't get parsed. Can I modify the `jar" basedir=".">` statement or find another workaround to substitute values in the XNL?

```
set project=TEST

echo[ 2>build.xml
for /f "useback delims=" %%_ in (%0) do (
  if "%%_"=="___ATAD___" set $=
  if defined $ echo(%%_ >> build.xml
  if "%%_"=="___DATA___" set $=1
)
goto :eof

___DATA___
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="%project%" default="jar" basedir="."> 
</project>
___ATAD___
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the delayedexpansion to get the value of your variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set project=TEST

echo[ 2>build.xml
for /f "delims=" %%_ in (%~nx0) do (
  if "%%_"=="___ATAD___" set $=
  if defined $ echo(%%_ >> build.xml
  if "%%_"=="___DATA___" set $=1
)
goto :eof

___DATA___
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="!project!" default="jar" basedir="."> 
</project>
___ATAD___
```

Another solution is to get the line number of a defined string (`@XML`in my example) with `Findstr` and then get the lines after this string using `More`.

Example :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set project=TEST

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /Bn "@XML" %~nx0') do set /a $Line=%%a 2>nul
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('more +%$Line% %~nx0') do echo %%a) >build.xml

goto :eof

@XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="!project!" default="jar" basedir="."> 
</project>
```